# [iOS][Background] updating map pins | drawing lines

Tags: ios, objective-c, dictionary, annotations, line

Hy :)

I am trying to update in background the position of the device (iPhone) and it works with the simulator http://grab.by/meLq (the annotations are only added in Background).

But when I am testing with my iPhone it does not work, I have got a line between the last position (before being in background) and the position when the becomes active.

What about the coding ?

I made a test of making a list when the app is in background and when the application becomes active again I load the list of positions recorded. (work with the simulator)

```
    - (void)handleAddLocations {
        NSLog(@"%s | %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, self.locationBackgroundList);

        if ([self.locationBackgroundList count] > 0) {
            for (CLLocation *backgroundLocation in self.locationBackgroundList) {

                if (YES){
                    LocAnnotation* annotation = [[LocAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:backgroundLocation.coordinate];
                    NSLog(@"%s %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, [annotation description]);
                    [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
            }

        MKUserLocation *userLocation = [[MKUserLocation alloc] init];
        [userLocation setCoordinate:backgroundLocation.coordinate];

        [self mapView:self.mapView didUpdateUserLocation:userLocation];

         }
        [self.mapView updateConstraints];

        [self.locationBackgroundList removeAllObjects];
        self.locationBackgroundList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
      }
  }
```

Thanks for helping ;)

Comment: How are you setting up the CLLocationManager?

Comment: `- (void)setup
{
    self.locationManager = [CLLocationManager new];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
 
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    self.isUpdatingLocation = NO;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a better option to add the annotation by creating a list in of locations in background.This is not possible to manage uielements when the app is in background.For this you should add all the positions in array while yous app is in background.

Comment: Now it is working I had to add locations on main thread [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(handleAddLocations) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];

Comment: Moreover with the simulator all is working fine but with my phone I got bad accuracy like 200 meters. **Any idea ?**

Comment: for location manager you should set the accuracy best then you will get the exact result.